# How to start developing an Sphero-Ball Windows Application in C#?

Tags: c#, sphero-api, sphero

I have a Sphero 2.0 ball.

What do I need to connect it to Windows 7 and to start developing applications for the ball (preferably in C#).

I tried to connect it via Bluetooth. While "pairing" the ball, it started to blink in red, green, violet. But Windows told me that it couldn`t find the right driver.

It would be great if the developers of Sphero could contribute some developing HowTos.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you've solved this problem yet, but I've successfully managed to communicate with the Sphero using .NET in windows 7. I began by reading this post:

http://thomasbladh.com/2013/01/01/balls-out-fun-with-the-sphero/

This is a good place to get started. I then re-implemented it because the receiving of packets back from Sphero wasn't quite right, and it dropped some. Using the above will get you as far as sending and running orbbasic code to the sphero, though.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently developing a "lowlevel" API for Sphero in C++. The only dependency is a working bluetooth stack and a C++ compiler. I am also thinking about making the API C-Style with only POD but at the moment this fits my needs:

https://github.com/PaulFreund/SpheroRAW

It should be easy to use from C# and even add a event based interface.